# How to change background of a cell that's being drag with iOS11+ drag-n-drop?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement the new drag-n-drop methods in UICollectionView and can't figure out how to remove the background from a cell that's being dragged.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    let parameters = UIDragPreviewParameters()
    parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
    return parameters
}
```

Problem is, it doesn't really work. The background is still visible. I'm thinking of using `visiblePath: UIBezierPath`, but I don't think it's going to play nice with text.

Is there a way to just remove this background completely?

Comment: It's as if nobody ever even tried to use the new drag-n-drop. Not a single question about it is answered and all the tutorials focus only on the most basic stuff.

Comment: adding `parameters.shadowPath = .init()` worked for me

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure there is a way to do so without using `UIBezierPath`.

Here is an example of what I did for something similar:

```
final class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var mySuperLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var whiteSubview: UIView! // I have added a cornerRadius of 12.0 in the XIB
}
```

[image]

Then, the delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragPreviewParametersForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let previewParameters = UIDragPreviewParameters()
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.whiteSubview.frame, cornerRadius: 12.0)
    previewParameters.visiblePath = path
    previewParameters.backgroundColor = .clear
    return previewParameters
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. I ended up reverting to the old D&D style, without the new APIs.

Comment: works great for me. I also implemented the same code with `dropPreviewParametersForRowAt`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use ItemProvider when a drag will begin.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    dragItem.previewProvider = { () -> UIDragPreview? in
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) // Do cell preview modifications here
        cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell?.backgroundColor = .clear
        return UIDragPreview(view: cell!)
    }
    return [dragItem]
}
```

Comment: Didn't work in my case but I guess my cell's a bit customized so maybe it'll work for others. It looks promising