# How to remove drop shadow of the cell while dragging?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionviewcell, dropshadow

I have a collectionView with drag-drop functionality. However, I want to avoid cell shadow on dragging.
I found some solutions using `dragPreviewParametersForItemAt` function, but I am not sure what parameters to return.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @anton68 Not yet :/

Comment: .... and how about now? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry @PinguinDirk, I kinda gave up and no more working on it.

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54714488/5790492

Answer (score 7):

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? UICollectionViewCell else {
        return nil
    }
    let previewParameters = UIDragPreviewParameters()
    previewParameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.frame)
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        previewParameters.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: .zero)
    }
    return previewParameters
}
```